# Temporary Directories in WebLogic 10

Tags: java, weblogic, weblogic-10.x

Whenever, WL is stopped it doesn't delete its temporary directories .. i.e.

`domains/mydomain/servers/myserver/tmp/_WL_TEMP_APP_DOWNLOADS`

`/domains/mydomain/servers/myserver/tmp/_WL_user/
/domains/mydomain/servers/myserver/stage`

and because of this, when we deploy new application, it doesn't deploy some JSP or some classes and it keeps the old version of those files. resulting in lots of business errors + runtime error.

Is it a known issue ? How can we tackle it?

Answer (score 5):

In general WL will cache your deployment and won't redeploy unless it is asked to. But it depends on how you deployed your application and if the server is in production or development mode. See [development deployments](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24443/autodeploy.htm#g1035158)  and [production deployments](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24443/redeploy.htm#i1032371).

One easy fix, go to the **/domains/mydomain/servers/myserver/** directory and delete:

- **tmp**
- **cache**
- **logs**

and leave the **data** and **security** directory.  Then restart. This will force WL to redeploy.

My original answer included a delete of the **data** directory but as @g-demecki and @j23 point out below, that can mess up an admin server. I believe it is OK to delete the **data** directory on a managed server.

Comment: From my experience deleting **data** directory is a serious mistake.

Comment: as per [Oracle forum](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2542496?tstart=0) **data** is crucial for admin server: _On AdminServer I recomend you to delete only tmp, logs and cache.
On any managed server you can delete any sub directory. No restrictions. It will be recreated as soon as you start it again._

Answer (score 1):

I never run into such issue in production mode, if you are running in development mode and using auto deploy, please follow best practices documented

> You must touch the REDEPLOY file (alter its timestamp) any time you
>   wish to trigger redeployment of an auto-deployed application. Even if
>   you modify an application while a server is shut down, you must touch
>   REDEPLOY to ensure that changes are applied when the server next
>   starts up.

Answer (score 0):

Redeploy should update the tmp - maybe your timestamps are not ok ?
Stop and start will not refresh tmp as it is still used after restart.

From my experience it is enough to delete tmp when server is down to force unpack WAR (it is a matter of unpacking WAR to tmp by Weblogic, this is the main task done during deployment).
e.g. in your case

```
/domains/mydomain/servers/myserver/tmp/
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, a simple reboot of the Linux machine fixed the issue.

Comment: This should be a comment instead. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post;](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment)