# Deleting temporary directories from weblogic server

Tags: unix, weblogic

Before starting weblogic server I want to delete temporary directories that weblogic creates, I see below directories in my Admin Server:

path: user_projects/domains/my_domain/servers/AdminServer

```
cache
sysman
adr
data
logs
tmp
```

and below for my Managed Server:

path: user_projects/domains/my_domain/servers/MyManagedServer

```
cache
data
logs
stage
tmp
```

I have installed my WLS 10.3.6 in production mode on my Linux box, what all directories I can delete? Also I read that deleting some files here will make WLS to re-deploy the applications once again, is that true?

I am new to using weblogic so confused on if I delete any files will cause any issues.

Comment: You can safely delete tmp, logs, data and cache folder without any issues (assuming server is not running). No idea about the other folders.

Comment: Someone asked pretty much the same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12301976/temporary-directories-in-weblogic-10 What I would do for the managed server is move the entire directory and then try to start it from the admin console. This will force weblogic to re-create the directory and you can see how it behaves and what comes back.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12301976/temporary-directories-in-weblogic-10/12368074#12368074

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can delete **tmp, cache** safely, but do not delete log, if you don't want log folder just take a back up or rename the folder[mv log log.bkp.date] and then delete the original log folder. Sometimes if the server stops running as admin you have to check the log files, or provide log files if any one asks in your work environment.

Answer (score 4):

As G. Demecki mentions, do not delete the data directory on the admin server as you will lose the embedded LDAP that weblogic uses for the DefaultAuthenticator.

tmp and cache directories are fine to remove, do it when the server is not running.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete .DAT and .LOK files with this code:

```
rm -f /home/Oracle/Middleware/user_projects/domains/bifoundation_domain/servers/bi_server1/tmp/bi_server1.lok
rm -f /home/Oracle/Middleware/user_projects/domains/bifoundation_domain/servers/bi_server1/data/ldap/ldapfiles/EmbeddedLDAP.lok
rm -f /home/Oracle/Middleware/user_projects/domains/bifoundation_domain/servers/AdminServer/data/ldap/ldapfiles/EmbeddedLDAP.lok
rm -f /home/Oracle/Middleware/user_projects/domains/bifoundation_domain/servers/bi_server1/data/store/default/_WS_BI_SERVER1000000.DAT
rm -f /home/Oracle/Middleware/user_projects/domains/bifoundation_domain/servers/bi_server1/data/store/diagnostics/WLS_DIAGNOSTICS000000.DAT
rm -f /home/Oracle/Middleware/user_projects/domains/bifoundation_domain/servers/AdminServer/data/store/default/_WLS_ADMINSERVER000000.DAT
rm -f /home/Oracle/Middleware/user_projects/domains/bifoundation_domain/servers/AdminServer/data/store/diagnostics/WLS_DIAGNOSTICS000000.DAT
rm -f /home/Oracle/Middleware/user_projects/domains/bifoundation_domain/servers/AdminServer/tmp/AdminServer.lok
```

Comment: or just do: `del /S /F *.lok` and `del /S /F *.dat`

Answer (score 0):

The cache directory only needs to delete these two directories.
cache
tmp